# When designing something in OO

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

..where do you begin?

As a basis for any design - for instance a package - where do you as a developer start.

I start by mapping out the requirements and breaking them down into sub categories and from this objects and methods.

Usually takes a while before I start drawing it out by hand - then that goes through a few versions. But I always have the underlying feeling I'm never finished and it could just be better. How can I overcome this?

And once I have my own design ideas I'm never sure how to incorporate design patterns into it.

How much time is justifiably spent designing for OO? (obviously it depends on the project at hand)

Comment: This is a discussion question and as such belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concerning the feeling that you somehow could do better - you will never overcome that and you shouldn't try, because this basically tells you that you're critical towards your own work and you're willing to learn/improve yourself. And this is the most valuable resource you have as a developer...

Thomas

Comment: Confidence is something that grows with experience. Trying/doing/seeing and feedback from reviews or community sites is good for this.

Comment: Indeed.  Reducing this feeling can only come from experience, both personal and from mentor/peers.  I caution you to never feel like you've gotten it perfect.  The feeling of perfection is the first step towards complacent arrogance, which leads to the bad kind of laziness.

Answer (score 2):

The way I like to explain it to new programmers, and that helped me when I was starting out, is to begin by identifying all the adjectives, verbs and nouns in a *simple* problem statement of some sort. From the nouns you can identify things that make good candidates for classes. From the adjectives you can identify things which make good candidates for member variables and finally from the verbs you can identify potential methods.

In the past I've suggested doing this by underlining/highlighting each of them in a different colour. You can also identify actors in use cases like this.

Clearly this won't work for all problems and it's easy enough to make up trivial examples where it wouldn't be sensible, but from a starting point for designing a set of classes I find it's a helpful way to think about it.

Inserting design patterns typically comes at a later stage than this and usually for me at least it's a question of spotting some kind of problem and either just knowing (from memory, e.g. command pattern for undo/redo) or seeing that the solution you're thinking about is similar to something else you've seen previously.

Comment: so maybe i shouldn't try and force myself to use/look for one?

Comment: I'd totally agree with that. Design patterns are "nuggets" of tried and tested good practice but you can still implement good practice regardless of if you look for named chunks of it. More often than not you'll probably be doing something close to a design pattern anyway and the risk of forcing a design pattern on something that doesn't fit is that you over complicate things. It's worth reading and being familiar with common design patterns to broaden your experience but I wouldn't stress about it too much!

Answer (score 2):

It depends: there are 2 main streams.

- Create a big architecture, with a lot of interfaces and abstract classes for everything (readUserInput() for instance)
- Create *just what you need* (more [AGILE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development) methode, see [KISS Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle))

If you choose the second one, you will be lead to improve what you've done, and then, abstract your layer. There you will begin inherence and so one to [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

In facts, we sometime want to create something really great for a very small need. I like the second one. Hope this helps, at least a little.

Answer (score 1):

> But I always have the underlying feeling I'm never finished and it could just be better.

That's good, because in practice the design is seldom finished (or optimal in the strict sense of the word) and it is almost always possible to make it better. At some point you simply have to write the thing. Watch for things that feel awkward, too complex to implement, not maintainable, for parts that give you headaches. These are the things that have to be designed better. Be prepared to rewrite the code over and over, as the key to good design and good code is iteration. Nobody writes perfect code at the first attempt.

This all feels quite abstract, because there are preciously little advices that would apply to all situations without exception. For example one of the basic rules is to keep the code simple, but generalization sometimes helps a great deal, even if it may seem more complex at the beginning. In the end it's usually a question of balance.

Think about the design for some time, then write the code. Look for what feels wrong, repeat from step one. There is no silver bullet.

Answer (score 0):

Design is arguably the most important step in the development process.  The less of a clear objective you have, the more likely you're going to have to rip everything out and start over.  When you're designing, design patterns should flow naturally into what you're creating, while you're creating it.

But the most important part is to first outline what you want, then point out what you need in order to get you there.  Take your time, because the design stage is important.

There's a wealth of resources on OO design out on the internet that can be of assistance, because we can't obviously write you an OO design book.  Good luck, and happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

This feels more like a confidence issue.  Which is normal - this stuff is hard.  Programming demands perfection and precognition to be done the best, and to my knowledge no member of the human race has this.

I've been trying to improve my abilities to design something in an OO way (albeit in C++, but many of the same principles apply to other OO languages), and here's the steps I've taken:

- Maybe spend some time getting used to the ideas/methods of refactoring.  Refactoring is an idea that 'you can change an OO design if its not correct, or to make it better.'  Really, you can - **which means that if you messed up, you can go back and fix it**.  Books on refactoring talk about techniques to make this easier.  I found reading that book helped me realize that there are ways to fix mistakes you make, and I found it eased my design fears.  It doesn't mean you do a bad design, but it does mean you have a bit of a safety net and you can go back and fix it.  ***You can only design to the best of your ability, and no more.***  ***So don't fret if you have to go back and fix it.***
- Robert Martin's tomes/writings on OO design are things I've found helpful.  I've been reading through his *Designing Object-Oriented C++ Applications Using the Booch Method* book, and while its old, it goes through case studies on designing complex OO systems in a very methodical, step-by-step way.  His newer books, I've found, are helpful in that regard too, but tend to present the same material in a more terse fashion.
- Work with colleagues on ideas to improve OO designs.

Comment: I thought refactoring was improving names in the code, splitting methods up into seperate methods if need be and so on. Have i missed the point with this one?

Comment: @Franco - No, but according to Martin Fowler, "Refactoring is the process of changing a software system in such a way that it does not alter the external behavior of the code yet improves on its internal structure."  If you get the internal structure wrong, ie. your design isnt quite up to snuff, refactoring techniques can help you shore up that part of the app to allow you to make more changes. "Improving the design after it has been written" - this is essentially the goal of refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest Peter Coad's Java Design as a good guide for doing OO/Java design?
Something much more heavy weight and rigorous: [http://www.amazon.com/Applying-UML-Patterns-Introduction-Object-Oriented/dp/0131489062/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1288364561&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131489062)

As for starting with Reqs- I suggest writing *brief* use cases and tie reqs to them so the reqs are in context.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer to your question could be: Begin with the test. There's a lot of ideas and discussion around "test driven development", and I like Scott Ambler's argument:

If it's worth building, it's worth testing.

See [Martin Fowler's brief intro](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDrivenDevelopment.html) or Scott Ambler's longer article (www.agiledata.org/essays/tdd.html) as a start, if this approach sounds interesting to you. It helped me a lot with good design.